# VirtualBox error in Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: virtualbox, 19.10

I have a problem with VirtualBox.
When I put the .iso file in (Settings->Storage->Empty), I always get:

[image: this error]

I have installed the extension pack for this version of VirtualBox, but I get the same error.
What should I do? I use Ubuntu 19.10

Comment: Disable Secure Boot in BIOS.

Comment: Thanks .It's done

Comment: So does it work now?